# Error at argument must be a react element, but you passed undefined

Tags: node.js, reactjs, material-ui

I started developing a new app in react and material ui, have encountered an issue:

> Error: React.cloneElement(...): The argument must be a React element, but you passed undefined.

Hence I haven't written any logical code yet, I've just started with react and material ui. A solution and guidance to this issue will be really very helpful.

Here is the code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { MenuItem, FormControl, Select } from "@material-ui/core";
import './App.css';

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="app">
      <h1></h1>
      <FormControl className="app_dropdown">
        <Select variant = "Outlined" value = "abc">
          <MenuItem value="worldwide">Worldwide</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value="worldwide">Option 2</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value="worldwide">Worldwide</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value="worldwide">Worldwide</MenuItem>
        </Select>
      </FormControl>

      {/* { Header } */}
      {/* { Title + Select input dropdown field } */}

      {/* { Info Box1 } */}
      {/* { Info Box2 } */}
      {/* { Info Box3 } */}

      {/* { Table } */}
      {/* { Graph } */}

      {/* { Map } */}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`variant` should be in small-case `outlined` and also please pass the `value` and `onChange` props to select

```
function App() {
const [country, setCountry] = useState("")
  return (
    <div className="app">
      <h1></h1>
      <FormControl className="app_dropdown">
        <Select variant = "outlined" value = {country} onChange={(e) => setCountry(e.target.value)}>
          <MenuItem value="India">India</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value="USA">USA</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value="UK">UK</MenuItem>
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the Material UI's `Select` component's `variant` prop is case-sensitive. 
It allows values `'filled' | 'outlined' | 'standard'`

So, to solve this just make `Outlined` into `outlined`

```
<Select variant = "outlined" value = "abc">
```